# linphone-iOS CallKit crashed in background

Tags: ios, swift, callkit, pushkit

I am using the linphone sdk on iOS

I used PushKit to receive incoming calls and used CallKit to display calls

Callkit works properly when the app is in the foreground
But when the app is completely closed, the app crashes when it receives the incoming push.

In the didReceiveIncomingPushWith method, when the push is received, I immediately call reportNewIncomingCall
But it crashes in the background.

[image]

Comment: did you do this: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019-707/?time=583 ("And new this year, it's very important that you know that you must report incoming calls with CallKit in the didReceiveIncomingPush callback or your app will be terminated.")

Answer (score 4):

On iOS 13.0 and above, VoIP push notifications must be handled by call kit. Receiving a VoIP push and not handling it through call kit result in your app crashing. This behavior is intended.

Comment: It is handled with callKit and works well in the foreground
But the crash occurs in the background

Comment: do you mean when app is open callkit is working?
but if app is closed callkit will crash?

Comment: Exactly, When the app is open or in try it works well. But when it is completely closed, it crashed.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/pkpushregistrydelegate/2875784-pushregistry

See the link above. You have to report the call immediately to call kit when using voip push notifications. If you're sending notifications when the app is close through push kit without immediately notifying call kit you will get that error.

Comment: @amirhoushmand We are also developing callkit + linphone. Do you have a fix for the problem?

Comment: yes it fixed. whats the problem?